# SharpBits crashes after 60 jobs have been added, how to extend?

Tags: c#, bit

The issue I have is that when I am downloading all the 'Slides' from the server, if there is more than 60 the application will crash. The reason for this is that SharpBits does not allow more than 60 Jobs.

Is there a way I can set the maximum amount of Jobs in code for this?

This is where I instantiate the SharpBits:

```
Global.gBitsMan = new BitsManager();
Global.gBitsMan.EnumJobs();
```

Comment: This seems to be a [group policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408626.aspx), so it could be forced upon a system by a domain.